# tcpdump. Capture packets to target host

Tags: tcpdump, wifi-direct

I have tcpdump on one device and i know IP of another device.
How can I get packages, which devices using for communication? 
Now I use something like `tcpdump -i <network_interface> -s 0 -w <file>` But i need to catch initial packages too. 
Tcpdump can't start with nonexistent network interface.
Is it possible to catch all packages sended from (and to) device with known IP?

Comment: What operating system is the machine on which you'd run tcpdump running?

Comment: tcpdump running on linux.

Comment: Hey @StepanLoginov... did my below answer help? Is that what you wanted? I'm curious since I'm not sure I interpreted it correctly...

Answer (score 1):

As this is Linux, if the problem is that network interfaces may appear after you've started capturing, try capturing on the "any" device:

```
tcpdump -i any -s 0 -w <file> host 10.1.1.1
```

which will capture on all interfaces, including ones that appear after tcpdump starts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow you, but if what you want is to ammend the command you are using so as to capture traffic to and from a device with a known IP, you just need to add the corresponding expression at the end, following pcap-filter guidelines.

In your case, and assuming you want all traffic to and from 10.1.1.1:

```
tcpdump -i <network_interface> -s 0 -w <file> host 10.1.1.1
```

tcpdump will capture only traffic that is evaluated as TRUE for the expression. pcap-filter will allow you to set protocols, source and destination IP addresses and tcp or udp ports or portranges, Ethernet MAC addresses, packet lengths and a myriad other things.

See http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html for general tcpdump usage, and http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.txt for all pcap-filter possibilities.